# Best combination of indexes and partitions for large Oracle tables with many lookups?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

I have an Oracle 10g database of genomic data with several >100 million row tables that look similar to the following:

```
ID    AssayID    Sample      Mutation    Call Frequency
101   12578      Sample01    T367G       P    0.87
102   31384      Sample01    A2345C      A    0.28
103   3453       Sample01    T247C       P    0.67
104   12578      Sample02    G235del     M    0.11
105   7868       Sample02    None        P    0.98
```

- `ID` is a unique PK, `AssayID` and `Sample` are foreign keys.
- Assume that for each `Sample` value, there are ~50k rows.
- Each `AssayID` occurs exactly once per `Sample`.
- `Mutation` is relatively random and `Call` can be one of three values.
- Queries on this table can use any one or a combination of the `AssayID`, `Sample`, `Mutation`, `Call`, or a value in a linked table via `AssayID` and `Sample`.

A typical query:

```
select t.*
from this_table t
    join assay_table a on t.assayid = a.assayid
    join sample_table s on t.sample = s.sample
where 
    s.name = 'xxx' and a.gene in ('abc', 'xyz') and t.call = 'P'
```

- Queries against these tables always join multiple smaller tables.
- The `WHERE` statement will usually filter data on multiple columns, but *never* from only the base data table.

How do I design the table to get the best query performance when selecting all columns?
Do I use indexes only, partitions only, or a combination of the two?  Disk space and insert/update performance is not an issue.

Comment: When you say "combination", do you mean AND or OR?

Comment: Both.  I am curious whether a combination of indexes and partitioning schemes, or just partitions, or just indexes would give me the best query performance in the situation I have described.

Comment: If there are ~50k rows for each unique value of `name`, each `attr2` occurs 1k times per name, where is the other multiplier of 50 coming from?  If each `attr1` and `otherID` occurs once per name, that only leaves `id` to generate the additional 50x multiplier which seems odd.  The table you're describing also seems to be very denormalized-- if there are 1000 different `attr2` values for each `name`, that implies that `attr2` ought to be in a different table that is related to this one using a primary key.  Why aren't you normalizing the table if you are concerned about performance?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: partitioning to improve performance will only work properly if your queries ***always*** contain the partitioning key.

Comment: @Justin Cave: Sorry, this table representation is a little simplistic, but I have tried to represent the fields that would be queried upon.  I have updated my question to include more data columns for a better picture.  As for normalization, this database is very heavily normalized.  Data tables like this are often linked to multiple annotation tables (eg via OtherID), which can have 10+ child tables.  Sometimes columns like Attr2 have no additional metadata, so there is no need for another table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If a query against partitioned tables does not include the partition key, will a full table scan of all partitions always occur?  If so, that would eliminate partitioning from my options, since the queried columns can vary.

Comment: If the query doesn't filter on the partitioning key, you'd either have to scan all partitions, scan a global index, or scan all the partitions of a local index to fetch the data.  I'm having a hard time reconciling your description of a "very heavily normalized" table with a description of this table where data is repeated 50k times.  If there is a 1:many relationship between a `name` and an `attr2`, `attr2` should be in a separate table.  If the table is actually normalized, perhaps some sample data would help us understand how to reconcile your descriptions.

Comment: Added some example data that will hopefully help.

Comment: You don't really get "best performance out of a table", but just out of queries against this table. To be able to answer your question, we'd need to see all or just the important queries against this table.

Comment: @Rob van Wijk: Fair enough.  Generally queries against these tables would retrieve all columns.

Comment: Thank you for all of the constructive comments.  I am continuting to edit the question to make it more informative and easier to answer.  I know this is something of an impossible question to definitively answer.

Comment: What if in the given example I were to partition the table by `Sample` and create a globally partioned index on `Mutation`? If 90% of queries reference `Sample` and 10% reference `Mutation`, would this make sense? As far as I can tell, indexing and partitioning the example table make no difference if the query filters only on a column in a joined table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating numerous test copies of tables with different combinations of indexes and partitions, and running a battery of performance analyses using a broad selection of queries, I don't think that there is a single, simple answer for this question.  Each situation is different, and the scope of this question is too broad for this forum.  Thank you everyone for the feedback, it was all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you could run Oracle's [SQL Access Advisor](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-sqlaccessadvisor-084929.html) and see what recommendations it provides.

Comment: Unfortunately, Enterprise Manager does not work correctly on my machine, so I cannot try SQL Access Advisor.

Comment: If you have an Oracle support account, download and apply patch 8350262. Enterprise manager for 10g fails during installation due to an expired certificate

Comment: The problem seems to be due to bad syntax in the tnsnames.ora file (which is odd, since I don't have this trouble with any other application that reads it). I have not yet located the problem, but I will test this when I get it figured out.  I'm currently waiting to get the patch applied.